# Window functions - Calculating the difference between current and previous records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have records like so -

```
patient claim   provider  date
460057  25494   3982      20200408
460057  25495   3982      20200410
46037   2592    396       20210110
46037   2593    393       20201210
46037   2594    394       20201114
```

I want to partition records by patient_id and order them by claim. Then I want to find the difference between the dates of the claims. Note that different patients can have different number of claims.

The output I am expecting is -

```
patient claim   provider  date        diff
460057  25494   3982      20200408    2
460057  25495   3982      20200410    0
46037   2592    396       20210110    31
46037   2593    393       20201210    26
46037   2594    394       20201114    0
```

31 is the difference between `20201210` and `20210110` dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dates are stored as *dates*, then you can just use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(date) over (partition by patient order by date) - date as diff
from t;
```

If `date` is a string or number, then you should fix the data, so dates are stored as dates.  You can also convert to a date in the query itself.